# Making a line shorter. 80 character limit

Tags: javascript

How would I be able to make this line shorter?

```
const otherVideos = (video) => video.getVideoUrl() !== player.getVideoUrl();
```

**Would I be able to split it in half somehow?**

https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/6/

```
 function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        const player = event.target;
        if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            const otherVideos = (video) => video.getVideoUrl() !== player.getVideoUrl();
            const pauseVideo = (video) => video.pauseVideo();
            players.filter(otherVideos).forEach(pauseVideo);
        }
        const playerVars = player.b.b.playerVars;
        if (playerVars.loop && event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            player.seekTo(playerVars.start);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `const otherVideos = v => v.getVideoUrl() != player.getVideoUrl();` You can make your line shorted by changing the variable name and removing the `()`... not sure if this is what your after

Comment: Beware of slavish devotion to rules of thumb. They're heuristics, not commandments from on high etched into stone tablets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to just use explicit return with a `{`, rather than implicit return:

```
const otherVideos = (video) => {
  return video.getVideoUrl() !== player.getVideoUrl();
};
```

Or, if you prefer, use implicit return and `(` instead:

```
const otherVideos = (video) => (
  video.getVideoUrl() !== player.getVideoUrl() // no semicolon
);
```

Also, if `player.getVideoUrl()` doesn't change over multiple iterations, then you could put it into a variable in advance, and then simply access that variable:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  const player = event.target;
  const playerURL = player.getVideoUrl();
  if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    const otherVideos = (video) => video.getVideoUrl() !== playerURL;
    const pauseVideo = (video) => video.pauseVideo();
    players.filter(otherVideos).forEach(pauseVideo);
  }
  const playerVars = player.b.b.playerVars;
  if (playerVars.loop && event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    player.seekTo(playerVars.start);
  }
}
```

(longest line is 66 characters, plus 4 for indentation)

You could also use anonymous functions instead of putting the `filter` and `forEach` callbacks into their own variables:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  const player = event.target;
  const playerURL = player.getVideoUrl();
  if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    players
      .filter(video => video.getVideoUrl() !== playerURL)
      .forEach(video => video.pauseVideo());
  }
  const playerVars = player.b.b.playerVars;
  if (playerVars.loop && event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    player.seekTo(playerVars.start);
  }
}
```

(now, the longest line is the one with `if (playerVars.loop...`)

Comment: JSLINT: // Expected ‘function’ and instead saw ‘=>’.
const otherVideos = (video) => {  // How would I fix that? 1st Code Example https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/17/

      const otherVideos = (video) => {
        return video.getVideoUrl() !== player.getVideoUrl();
      };

Comment: The syntax is correct, is there an error *label*, such as one that can be looked up [here](http://lint-explain.herokuapp.com/use-the-or-operator/)? Perhaps your environment isn't set up for ES6+ syntax?

Comment: Everything is check-marked and that error is still coming up. https://www.jslint.com/  /// https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/17/

Comment: JSLint doesn't seem to understand multi-line arrow functions, unfortunately, which makes things difficult when you want to write concise code (that is, use arrow functions) *and* want to keep line length short (good for readability). I'd recommend using a modern linter like ESLint, JSLint is quite old and isn't happy with many (perfectly fine) things done nowadays.

Comment: Although you *could* fix it by using a full-fledged `function` instead of an arrow function, that's silly, it makes the code harder to read (IMO) for the sake of a bad linter rule.

Comment: This worked:      const otherVideos = function(video) {
            return video.getVideoUrl() !== player.getVideoUrl();
          };

Comment: How would I make this line shorter? const playerVars = Object.assign({}, oldSettings.playerVars, newSettings.playerVars); I'm not able to figure this one out. How would it be done? https://jsfiddle.net/89zwf62y/2/

Comment: Use spread syntax instead, and maybe declare the object over multiple lines: https://gist.github.com/CertainPerformance/a25b85a42f101cd700fbdc4ae1fb2311

Comment: I was told to do that, but I didn't know how it would be implemented. Could you provide an updated jsfiddle with that reccomendation? https://jsfiddle.net/89zwf62y/2/

Comment: Just check the gist link in the comment above - it shows how to do it. General idea is, any time you want to make a line shorter to make it more readable, don't be afraid to put in a line break, it'll *usually* be OK :)